# Copy lines containing trigger word from file using python

Tags: python

I have a file containing data which I'm only interested in specific lines. The file looks like this:

```
element:             H          He          Li          Be           B           C           N           O           F
 code:              100         200         300         400         500         600         700         800         900
 abundance:     12.0000     10.9300      1.0500      1.3800      2.7000      8.3900      7.7800      8.6600      4.5600
 numb-frc.:  9.2076D-01  7.8369D-02  1.0331D-11  2.2087D-11  4.6147D-10  2.2602D-04  5.5481D-05  4.2087D-04  3.3431D-08
 mass-frc.:  7.3831D-01  2.4955D-01  5.7046D-11  1.5836D-10  3.9689D-09  2.1596D-03  6.1822D-04  5.3569D-03  5.0527D-07

 element:            Ne          Na          Mg          Al          Si           P           S          Cl          Ar
 code:             1000        1100        1200        1300        1400        1500        1600        1700        1800
 abundance:      7.8400      6.1700      7.5300      6.3700      7.5100      5.3600      7.1400      5.5000      6.1800
 numb-frc.:  6.3701D-05  1.3619D-06  3.1199D-05  2.1585D-06  2.9795D-05  2.1093D-07  1.2710D-05  2.9117D-07  1.3936D-06
 mass-frc.:  1.0226D-03  2.4908D-05  6.0326D-04  4.6331D-05  6.6572D-04  5.1976D-06  3.2422D-04  8.2122D-06  4.4290D-05
```

I only need the lines called "mass-frc.:". 
Since I'm a complete beginner to python, I need help with this. 
I tried the following code, which is not working:

```
with open("Niminus.stdout","r") as fin, open("Niminus_massfrac.txt","w") as fout:
    string = " mass-frc.:"
    lines = fin.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if string in lines:
            fout.write(line)
```

Help is much appreciated, explanations as well, I'm eager to learn. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close! As others have noted you have check each line which can be done directly. I like the way you open both files so that I haven't changed.

---

First, you have to extract the line which I prefer doing with a comprehension list, where we sort out all lines that do not contain the word "mass-frc". This is much like a for-loop where you append the elements going through your if-statement to an already existing list, just much simpler. Oh and the `.strip` is just to clean up newline characters.

```py
lines = [line.strip() for line in fin if "mass-frc" in line]
```

Then we safely write the list of lines to the out file, by concatenating together the lines, so each will be on a separate line in the out file.

```py
fout.write("\n".join(str(line) for line in lines))
```

collecting it all we get something like the following:

```py
# open files safely
with open("Niminus.stdout", 'r') as fin, \
     open("Niminus_massfrac.txt", "w") as fout:

    # Find lines only containing relevant information
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fin if "mass-frc" in line]

    # dump line to files
    fout.write("\n".join(str(line) for line in lines))
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful and I learned something new, I'll implement now.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm still new to helping on SO, is there anything in the explanation that should be done differently? And remember to mark one of the solutions as the favoured one ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the line in the loop, not all the lines

```
if string in line: # not lines
    fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("Niminus.stdout","r") as fin:
   with open("Niminus_massfrac.txt","w") as fout:
    for line in fin.readlines():
        if "mass-frc." in line:
            fout.write(line)
```